# Deutscher Konjugator / German conjugation tables

Tags: verb

Wo kann ich einen "Deutsch-Konjugator" finden bzw. ihn herunterladen?

> Where can I find German conjugation tables?

Answer (score 4):

[Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu) bietet Tabellen für alle Wortformen an. LEO online verweist auch auf Canoo.net, was ja dafür spricht. Es gibt auch eine Offline-Wörterbuch-App fürs iPhone, leider noch nicht für andere Plattformen. Die meisten anderen Apps sind ja online, daher erwähne ich das.

> [Canoo.net](http://canoonet.eu) provides tables for all word forms. LEO online just uses Canoo.net. There's also an offline dictionary for iPhone, unfortunately not yet for other platforms though. Most other dictionary apps are online only, so I thought I'd mention it.

Answer (score 2):

[LEO online](http://dict.leo.org) gives the conjugations of words. Click on the little i beside a word.

Answer (score 1):

[Verbix](http://www.verbix.com/languages/german.shtml) has an online site and a Windows standalone version.

Answer (score 1):

[Reverso](http://conjugator.reverso.net/conjugation-german.html) is a website, not a downloadable program, but it gives all the conjugated forms of German verbs.

Answer (score 0):

[Logos Conjugator](http://www.logosconjugator.org/)

I don't know about its capabilities with the German language. I used it in context with Italian and Dutch.

I believe there are not only online versions. It has downloadable versions too.

Comment: Hat schon jemand von euch ein wichtiges, einzufügendes Wort oder vielleicht einen Fehler entdeckt?